# Cannot receive any messages or push notification because being blacklisted by Google

Tags: blacklist

Recently, I got some feedbacks from my users said that they cannot receive any messages or push notification in my app. And I found that there is an issue-

> String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()； token
>   Value is "Blacklisted" in system.

Please help me removing the blacklist from Google.

[image: Here is image for your reference]

Comment: please post your question clearly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Google support forum.